# Typing in Edittext lead to google search widget

Tags: android, android-edittext

I ran up with a strange problem. This is the code I have use for Edittext

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:singleLine="false" />
```

Whenever I run my app and start typing anything on the edittext. Google search widget comes up and start showing result based on my typed character. I didn't wrote any code for this.

Okay here I am posting the onCreate method of my activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // progress dialog
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", false);
    progressDialog.hide();

    final Spinner spinnerLanguage = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final EditText edittextSource = EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText edittextInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final Activity activity = this;
    textOutput = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textResult = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    // languages
    spinnerLanguage.setAdapter(new AdapterLanguages(this, 1));

    // execute button
    Button btnExecute = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //some code here
                }

    });
}
```

as soon as i type anything on edittext1, it is causing the following intent

> Starting activity: Intent { act=android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/.SearchActivity (has extras) }

Comment: You have to post a bit more code, like if you setup something in the edittext programmatically. Your layout is fine btw.

Comment: I didn't setup anything in my code. It is simple gettext() method I have called once when a button is clicked

Comment: post more code, so i can identify the bug and rectify it

Comment: I have another edittext (edittext2). When i type first in edittext2 and return to edittext1, this doesn't happen. Couldn't get what exactly is happening